# Apache2 process is repeating and website is down

Tags: apache, debian

My website is down i get error in browser

```
The connection was reset
```

And when I enter this command

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

I get this

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-02-18 17:33:53 EST; 1min 51s ago
  Process: 18873 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 15234 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18989 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─19003 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19007 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19008 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19009 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19010 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19011 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19015 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19016 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19017 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19018 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19019 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19020 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19021 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19022 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19023 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19024 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19025 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19026 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19027 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19028 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19029 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19030 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19031 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19032 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19033 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19034 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19035 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19036 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19037 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19038 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19039 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19040 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19041 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19042 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19043 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19044 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19045 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19046 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19047 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19048 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19049 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19050 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19051 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19052 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19053 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19054 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19055 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19056 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19057 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19058 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19059 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19060 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19061 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19062 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19063 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19064 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19065 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19066 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19067 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19068 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19069 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19070 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19071 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19072 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19073 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19074 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19075 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19076 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19077 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19078 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19079 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19080 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19081 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19082 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19083 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19084 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19085 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19086 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19087 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19088 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19089 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19090 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19091 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19092 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19093 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19094 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19095 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19096 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19097 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19098 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19099 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19100 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19101 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19102 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19103 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19104 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19105 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19106 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19107 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19108 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19109 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19110 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19111 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19112 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19113 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19114 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19115 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19116 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19117 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19118 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19119 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19120 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19121 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19122 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19123 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19124 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19125 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19126 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19127 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19128 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19129 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19130 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19131 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19132 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19133 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19134 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19135 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19136 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19137 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19138 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19139 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19140 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19141 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19142 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19143 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19144 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19145 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19146 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19147 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19148 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19149 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19150 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19151 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19152 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19153 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19154 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19155 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19156 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19157 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19158 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─19159 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Feb 18 17:33:52 s3curity.tn apache2[18989]: Starting web server: apache2AH0055...e
Feb 18 17:33:53 s3curity.tn apache2[18989]: .
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

And each time i check the process keeps repeating ! 
My website doesn't work and when i enter `wget 127.0.0.1`

```
--2016-02-18 17:41:01--  (try: 2)  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I tried `killall apache2` then restarting the server but the same it just start repeating over and over again !

Weird problem!
Solution ?